# Android 4.4 WebView не работает скачивание файла при формировании .xls сервером

Tags: android, webview

Добрый день .
Надеюсь на вашу помощь )))) 
Сделал приложение типа свой браузер , в android 4.0-4.3 работает скачивание файла при формировании .xls сервером , в 4.4 скачивание динамической ссылки не работает .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView mWebView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // указываем страницу загрузки
    mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength)
        {
            Log.d( "3" ,"3");
        }
    });
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://ya.ru");
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
    {
        Log.i( "1" ,"1");
        String url = view.getUrl();
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d( "5" ,"5");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.i("2", "2");
        Context tt = view.getContext();
        Log.i("2", tt.toString());
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: В 4.4 не работает onDownloadStart , на 4.1 работает